# ¿Como instanciar un metodo de una clase en la clase principal? C#

Tags: c#, botón, clase

Muy buenas colegas.

Se que la pregunta parece muy tonta pero este problema me tiene un poco loco ya.

Alguna forma de instanciar en los dos botones sin tener q mandar elnparsmetro al constructor otra vez.

La cuestión es que tengo este código en la clase Cola:

```
    public Cola(int Tamaño)
    {
        Maximo = Tamaño;
        NoCarnet = new string[Maximo];
        Nombres = new string[Maximo];
        Apellidos = new string[Maximo];
        Carrera = new string[Maximo];
        Año = new string[Maximo];
        ClaseI = new string[Maximo];
        ClaseII = new string[Maximo];
        ClaseIII = new string[Maximo];
        NotaI = new int[Maximo];
        NotaII = new int[Maximo];
        NotaIII = new int[Maximo];
        Final = Frente = -1;
        MessageBox.Show("Se ha creado la cola " + Maximo + " datos");
    }

        public void Agregar_a_Cola(string MetNoCarnet, string MetNombre, string MetApellido, string  
        MetCarrera, string MetAño, string MetClaseI, int MetNotaI, string MetClaseII, int MetNotaII, 
        string MetClaseIII, int MetNotaIII)'
    {            
        if (ColaLlena() == false)
        {
            if (Final == Maximo - 1)
            {
                Final = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Final++;
                NoCarnet[Final] = MetNoCarnet;
                Nombres[Final] = MetNombre;
                Apellidos[Final] = MetApellido;
                Carrera[Final] = MetCarrera;
                Año[Final] = MetAño;
                ClaseI[Final] = MetClaseI;
                NotaI[Final] = MetNotaI;
                ClaseII[Final] = MetClaseII;
                NotaII[Final] = MetNotaII;
                ClaseIII[Final] = MetClaseIII;
                NotaIII[Final] = MetNotaIII;
                Form1 fm = new Form1();
                fm.dgvDatosUCC.Rows.Add(NoCarnet[Final], Nombres[Final], Apellidos[Final], 
                 Carrera[Final], Año[Final], ClaseI[Final], NotaI[Final], ClaseII[Final], 
                 NotaII[Final], ClaseIII[Final], NotaIII[Final]);
            }

            if (Frente == -1)
            Frente = 0;   
        }
    }
```

'''

y en la clase principal trato de instanciar estos metodos pero si instancio en la funcion del boton crear para capturar el tamaño del vector no podre volver a ponerlo en el metodo del boton agregar.

Esto en la clase principal:

```
    private void btnCrear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CapTamaño = int.Parse(txtTamañoCola.Text);
        Cola c = new Cola(CapTamaño);
    }

    private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        NoCarnetEs = txtNoCarnet.Text;
        NombresEs = txtNombres.Text;
        ApellidosEs = txtApellidos.Text;
        CarreraEs = cbCarrera.Text;
        AñoEs = cbAño.Text;
        ClaseIEs = txtClaseI.Text;
        ClaseIIEs = txtClaseII.Text;
        ClaseIIIEs = txtClaseIII.Text;
        NotaIEs = int.Parse(txtNotaClaseI.Text);
        NotaIIEs = int.Parse(txtNotaClaseII.Text);
        NotaIIIEs = int.Parse(txtNotaClaseIII.Text);

        c.Agregar_a_Cola(NoCarnetEs, NombresEs, ApellidosEs, CarreraEs, AñoEs, ClaseIEs, NotaIEs, 
        ClaseIIEs, NotaIIEs, ClaseIIIEs, NotaIIIEs); //Aca es el problema no puedo mandar a 
        instanciar este metodo.
    }
```

'''

Agradeceré mucho sus comentarios. Y si hay algo estética mente o lógicamente mal me disculpan amigos, también aceptare esos comentarios constructivos.

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero te da algún error en concreto ? Por otra parte, lo que logre entender es que no puedes hacer otra instancia en el botón agregar, por que lo hiciste en el botón crear. Si es eso. te recomiendo dejar el objeto de la clase cola como atributo del form y luego lo instancias en el botón crear y ya podrás llamar al método en el botón agregar.

Comment: Amigio, me podrias explicar graficamente como, creo q te entiendo, pero no del todo. Y si, el problema es ese. No me deja instanciar. Porque si vuelvo a poner Cola col = new Cola(); me vuelve a pedir que le envie un parametro al constructor.

Comment: ahí te deje un ejemplo como respuesta, espero te pueda ayudar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

En tu `Forms.cs` debes declarar un atributo privado, en tu caso de tipo Cola.
Esto permitirá que puedas acceder al objeto desde otros métodos, ya que cuando lo declaras en el método del botón crear, solo sera valido dentro de ese método y no desde otros.

Y con el modificador de acceso private evitas que pueda ser accedido y modificado desde otras clases.

El código debe quedar similar a lo siguiente:

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{
    private Cola cola;

    //Resto del código de tu Form

    private void btnCrear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CapTamaño = int.Parse(txtTamañoCola.Text);
        cola = new Cola(CapTamaño);
    }

    private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        NoCarnetEs = txtNoCarnet.Text;
        NombresEs = txtNombres.Text;
        ApellidosEs = txtApellidos.Text;
        CarreraEs = cbCarrera.Text;
        AñoEs = cbAño.Text;
        ClaseIEs = txtClaseI.Text;
        ClaseIIEs = txtClaseII.Text;
        ClaseIIIEs = txtClaseIII.Text;
        NotaIEs = int.Parse(txtNotaClaseI.Text);
        NotaIIEs = int.Parse(txtNotaClaseII.Text);
        NotaIIIEs = int.Parse(txtNotaClaseIII.Text);

        cola.Agregar_a_Cola(NoCarnetEs, NombresEs, ApellidosEs, CarreraEs, AñoEs, ClaseIEs, NotaIEs, 
        ClaseIIEs, NotaIIEs, ClaseIIIEs, NotaIIIEs); //Aca es el problema no puedo mandar a 
        instanciar este metodo.
    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Buena respuesta! Sólo considera explicar el porque se debe instanciar la clase como global y no local, puede ser que el OP no entienda la diferencia ;)

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Toda la razón, voy a editarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y por la explicacion. Cada dia se aprende algo nuevo Ha funcionado. :)

Comment: Si te ayudo puedes marcarla como respuesta correcta, a ver si le ayuda a alguien más. :D